# Multiple rewrite rules in .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to make pretty links using .htaccess. I am new to apache and can't really figure out why it is not working.

I have two pages:
`single_picture.php` and `single_video.php`

Both pages take two arguments : name, and cat_id/category_id

Here are two examples:
http://www.unclelol.com/single_picture.php?name=Real-time-images-5&cat_id=13

http://www.unclelol.com/single_video.php?name=football%20fail&category_id=22

And here is my `.htaccess`:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^pictures/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /single_picture.php?name=$2&cat_id=$1 
RewriteRule ^videos/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /single_video.php?name=$2&category_id=$1
```

Now for reasons unknown . The rewrite for pictures works perfectly:

http://www.unclelol.com/pictures/13/Real-time-images-5/

But the rewrite for videos gives 404 error:

http://www.unclelol.com/videos/22/football%20fail

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Ahmar

Answer (score 1):

Merge your both rules to single:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)s(?=/)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /single_$1.php?name=$3&cat_id=$2 [NE,L]
```

Also remove the pattern `([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)` which will not work for `%20` as you have in your video url. Instead use `([^/]+)` which matches any character until reaches `/`.